# Null values being passed when I post in php

Tags: php, html, forms, post, http-post

I am having trouble figuring out why no matter what the address and city fields are always null for me. I input any basic data, post it and get on the other side and it says it's null. Anything obvious I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

This is how I get the values passed via post:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address_one = $_POST['address_one'];
$address_two = $_POST['address_two'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
```

Form I use to collect the data:

```
 <form id='login' action='createreg.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
                <h3>Create an Account</h3>
                <table id='registertb'>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Username:</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type='text' name='username' id='username' class='loginfield' maxlength="50" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password:</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type='password' name='password' id='password' class='loginfield' maxlength="50" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email:</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type='text' name='email' id='email' class='loginfield' maxlength="50" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name:</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type='text' name='fname' id='fname' class='loginfield' maxlength="50" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Name:</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type='text' name='lname' id='lname' class='loginfield' maxlength="50" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Phone:</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type='text' name='phone' id='phone' class='loginfield' maxlength="50" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Address Line 1:</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type='text' name='address1' id='address1' class='loginfield' maxlength="50" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Address Line 2:</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type='text' name='address2' id='address2' class='loginfield' maxlength="50" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>City:</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type='text' name='address2' id='address2' class='loginfield' maxlength="50" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Age:</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type='text' name='age' id='age' class='loginfield' maxlength="50" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href='index.html'>Login</a></td>
                        <td align='right'>
                        <input type='submit' id='subbutton' value='Create' class='buttons' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: You're missing some stuff in your PHP handler. If you're wanting to send as email, your code is not in there.

Comment: If what you posted for your PHP handler is exactly that, then you're missing a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've named your inputs incorrectly. In your PHP, you use these to set the variables:

```
$address_one = $_POST['address_one'];
$address_two = $_POST['address_two'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
```

But the HTML references the address fields by number, and the city input is actually a duplicate of `address2`. You need to set the input `name` attributes to match what you're using inside the `$_POST` variables.